# Angular rxjs: Wating for observer_1 to complete before creating and subscribing to observer_2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've to observers the obser_user one will return the user_Id. Once I have the user Id I can create the obser_quests that gets the quests related to the user.

My issue here is that I can't create the obser_quests if I don't have the user_Id. Thus the only workaround is to nest the observer subscriptions, but this seems messy.

How can I fix it in clean way?

```
let obser_user:Observable<any> = this.userWebapiService.currentApplicationUserRead();
//Can't create the second observer, I need the user_Id from observer_first
// let obser_quests:Observable<any> = this.questWebapiService.countQuestsCreatedByUser(this.applicationUser_Id_current);


obser_user.subscribe(
  (resp: IApplicationUser_vmr)=>{
    console.log("ZR resp:", resp);
    this.applicationUser_Id_current = resp.id;

    //Nested observer created. Not good.
    let obser_quests:Observable<any> = this.questWebapiService.countQuestsCreatedByUser(this.applicationUser_Id_current);
    obser_quests.subscribe(
      (resp: number)=>{
        console.log("ZR resp:", resp);
        this.countQuestsCreatedByUser = resp;
        this.totalPages = resp;
      },
      (error:any)=>{
        console.log("ZR erros:", error);
      },
      ()=>{
        console.log("ZR oservable completed.");
    });  

  },
  (error:any)=>{
    console.log("ZR erros:", error);
  },
  ()=>{
    console.log("ZR oservable completed.");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { catchError, finalize, flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const obser_user = this.userWebapiService.currentApplicationUserRead();
obser_user.pipe(
  flatMap(user => this.questWebapiService.countQuestsCreatedByUser(user.id)),
  catchError(err => {
    // this is how you should handle errors
    console.log("ZR erros:", error);
  }),
  finalize(() => {
    // this is your finally block
    console.log("ZR oservable completed.");
  }),
).subscribe((questionCount: number) => {
  console.log("ZR resp:", questionCount);
  this.countQuestsCreatedByUser = questionCount;
  this.totalPages = questionCount;
});
```

I hope this helps. I've added how you should truly handle errors and finally blocks using [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) and [finalize](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html), respectively. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you'll need rxJs pipe operators. e.g. [flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)
With flatMap, you can map one observable's result to another observable.

```
this.userWebapiService.currentApplicationUserRead().pipe(
    flatMap(user => this.questWebapiService.countQuestsCreatedByUser(user.id))
).subscribe(questsCount => {
// do something with questCount
});
```

Comment: subscribe shows an error: "subscribe does not exist on type OperatorFunction<{}, object>" ?

Comment: probably you are missing some parenthesis

Comment: possible that subscribe should go at the end and not nested in pipe function? I've changed it like this, is this what you meant:     this.userWebapiService.currentApplicationUserRead()
    .pipe(
      flatMap(user  => this.questWebapiService.countQuestsCreatedByUser(user as string))
    ).subscribe(questsCount => {})

Comment: subscribe is after the pipe. Like it is in my code snippet ;)